Dissolving polygons within other polygons and accumulated one of their values in QGIS
I am planning a district heating system (pipe system in red). For this I need the total heat consumption of all cadastral units (in blue) next to the pipe to calculate the dimension. There are zero to n buildings (in yellow) on each cadastral unit. Not all of them have a value for heat consumption in the attribute table.
I planned to add up all the heat consumption values per cadastral unit and then add these units to the street itself. But I did not even manage to clip the buildings in their unit. I guess I need to dissolve the buildings within their unit.
How can I do this or is there a better way to do this than the one I described?


One possible approach is to first intersect the buildings with the cadastral units using the Intersection tool. This will give you the attributes from the cadastral layer in a new building layer.
You can then summarise the new layer using the Aggregate tool. When aggregating, use any unique attribute of the cadastral units for GROUP_BY.  Below this, select SUM as the aggregate function for the attribute with the consumption.
